# MYSQL is overloaded

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql server is overloading on executing these 2 queries.

UPDATE devices t1 INNER JOIN positions t2 on t1.id = t2.device_id set t1.latestPosition_id = (SELECT id FROM positions WHERE device_id = t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), t1.speed = (SELECT speed FROM positions WHERE device_id = t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

INSERT INTO positions (`altitude`, `course`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `power`, `speed`, `time`, `device_id`, `valid`) VALUES ('$faltitude[$i]','$fcource[$i]','$flatitude[$i]','$flongtitude[$i]','$fpower[$i]','$fspeed[$i]','$ftime[$i]','$fid[$i]','1')

Im a beginner and Im trying my level best to solve this issue.

Kindly help me.

Comment: This was the error code I get if It try execute it from phpmyadmin  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: What do you mean by *overloading*?

Comment: There's SQL syntax error on the first statement. A closing paren is missing on the second subquery (the end of the statement.)

Comment: The cpu usage was too high while executing the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is running two sub queries and updating all the records in the tables. Depending on how large the tables are and how strong your DB server is it would not surprise me that it locks up. For starters, you can try breaking it into two queries:

```
UPDATE devices t1 
INNER JOIN positions t2 ON t1.id = t2.device_id 
SET t1.latestPosition_id = (SELECT id FROM positions WHERE device_id = t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);

    UPDATE devices t1 
    INNER JOIN positions t2 on t1.id = t2.device_id set t1.speed = (SELECT speed FROM positions 
    WHERE device_id = t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Your syntax error in the second query is likely from passing variables like '$faltitude[$i]'. One of those variables probably have a value like "don't" and the ' is causing the sql to become invalid. You should use parameter binding or at least escape the input from single quotes.

Comment: Thank you I will check with this right now and get back to you